# d3 bar chart does not extend to full width of svg

Tags: d3.js

I have a bar chart (http://tributary.io/inlet/4720197) that plots a dataset with a large number of points that I can't get to fill the entire width of the svg.  I had the same issue with a line chart and was able to resolve by using rangePoints.

I've been attempting something similar with this chart but can't quite get the right combination (it's using two scales for the grouping) and am unclear how to get the side-by-side bars that I previously accomplished with rangeBand() given that function does not exist with rangePoints.  What am I missing?

[image: pic of bar chart]

Comment: Have you tried using rangeBands instead of rangeRoundBands, in particular for x0? I suspect with so many bars the rounding differences are accumulating to something significant.

Comment: Thanks, @Superboggly that worked.  Now to read the documentation another 100 times to understand the small difference making this work.  :)